# How can i fix this problem of " incompatible types"?

Tags: c

I want to make a program that returns the average of the numbers entered but i get this error:
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float *’ from type ‘float’

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CANT ((int)99)
float* promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant)
{
float *p;
int a;
float total;

  for ( a = dataCant; a >= 0; a--) {
    total += *dataPtr;
    *dataPtr +=1;
  }
  p = total / dataCant;
  return (p);
}

int main (void)
{
float v[CANT],*q;
int i;

printf ("Ingrese numeros para calcular el promedio\r\n");
printf ("Use -1 para ver el promedio\r\n");
while ((i < CANT) || (v [i] != -1)) {
  printf(" Ingrese un numero: \r \n");
  scanf ("%f", &v[i]);
  i++;
}
q = promedio (&v[0], i);

printf ("El promedio vale %f\r\n", *q);

free (v);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Why `float* p` in the first place? You're returning a pointer to a thing that never existed in the first place. Just return `float`.

Comment: `float* promedio`  -> `float promedio` and `float *p` -> `float p`. and `*q` -> `q`. You don't need pointers here

Comment: Also `float *dataPtr` -> `float dataPtr[]` (it's the same thing, but it better shows your intention) and `total += *dataPtr;` -> `total += dataPtr[a];` and remove `*dataPtr +=1;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I shoud use float* promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant) for this Yes or yes is part of the exercise

Comment: @tadman Because it is an exercise of pointers i should us a pointer

Comment: @SantiagoAle are you sure you did't misunderstand something? Because `promedio` returning a pointer doesn't make much sense here. Maybe they want you do have something like`void promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant, float *result)`. And call it like this: `float q; promedio (&v[0], i, &q);`. And in `promedio` : `*result = total / dataCant;` and drop `return (p);`  alltogether

Comment: @Jabberwocky maybe i made it wrong.

Comment: You can't just use pointers however you want, there's rules. This needs to *point to something*.

Comment: @Jabberwocky the task was this:

 Implement a function that calculates the average of a vector of type float. The prototype of the function is;

float avg(float *dataPtr, int dataCant);

where:

dataPtr: It is the pointer to the data.

dataCant: It is the number of elements of the pointed vector.

Comment: @SantiagoAle _"float avg(..."_ so no pointer returned here. You misread something. Therefore my answer below is not exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of returning a pointer from promedio doesn't make much sens.

You probably want this:

```
void promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant, float *result)
{
  int a;
  float total;

  for ( a = dataCant; a >= 0; a--) {
    total += *dataPtr;
    dataPtr +=1;    // remove the *, you want to increment the pointer
  }                 // not the thing it points to

  *result = total / dataCant;
}

int main (void)
{
  float v[CANT],*q;
  int i;

  printf ("Ingrese numeros para calcular el promedio\r\n");
  printf ("Use -1 para ver el promedio\r\n");

  while ((i < CANT) || (v [i] != -1)) {
    printf(" Ingrese un numero: \r \n");
    scanf ("%f", &v[i]);
    i++;
  }

  float q;
  promedio (&v[0], i);  // you should write `v` innstead of the cumbersome `&v[0]`

  printf ("El promedio vale %f\r\n", q); // q is a float, removge the *

  // remove free (v), you can only free stuff allocated via malloc and friends
  return (0);
}
```

Anyway, I have the strong impression you should read again the chapter dealing with pointers in your learning material.

It turns out you rather need this:

```
float promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant)
{
  int a;
  float total;

  for ( a = dataCant; a >= 0; a--) {
    total += *dataPtr;
    dataPtr +=1;    // remove the *, you want to increment the pointer
  }                 // not the thing it points to

  return = total / dataCant;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jabberwocky
Thank you for your answer, thanks it I managed to solve the exercise. This is the answer (works)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CANT ((int)99)
float promedio (float *dataPtr, int dataCant)
{
  int a;
  float total;

  for ( a = dataCant; a >= 0; a--) {
    total += *dataPtr;
    dataPtr +=1;   
  }

  return (total / dataCant);
}

int main (void)
{
  float v[CANT], q, a;
  int i=0;

  printf ("Ingrese numeros para calcular el promedio\r\n");
  printf ("Use -1 para ver el promedio\r\n");

  while ((i < CANT) && (a != -1)) {
    printf(" Ingrese un numero: \r \n");
    scanf ("%f", &a);

    if (a != -1) {
      v[i]=a;
      i++;
    }
  }

  q = promedio (&v[0], i);

  printf ("El promedio vale %0.2f\r\n", q);

  return (0);
}
```